# how to change the style of GWT checkboxcell?

Tags: java, css, gwt, datagridviewcheckboxcell

in gwt how do i change the style of checkboxcell? the checkboxcell is inside a gridtable and

`datagrid.getColumn(0).setCellStyleNames(SomeCssClass.getMyCss());`

does not work

here's a sample of my code

css:

```
  .checkBoxCss{
            height:25px;
        }
```

this is for java that extends CSSResource

```
public interface MyCSS extends CssResource {

    String checkBoxCss();

}
```

and this is for the Gridtable

```
class Gridtable{

public DataGrid<MyObject> createDatagrid(){


CheckboxCell myCheckbox= new CheckboxCell(true, false);

Column<MyObject, Boolean> checkCol = new Column<MyObject, Boolean>(myCheckbox) {
            @Override
            public Boolean getValue(MyObject object) {
                return object.isSelected();

            }
        };

}

datagrid.addColumn(checkCol, "Test");
datagrid.getColumn(0).setCellStyleNames(MyResrouces.INSTANCE.MyCSS().checkBoxCss());


}
```

Comment: What CSS rules are you trying to apply? Which CSS selectors do you use?

Comment: hmm ok i will make it simple. lets say left:0 or color:blue.

Comment: What selectors do you use? BTW, 'left:0' obviously won't work.

Comment: im not exactly sure on what selector is. But i set my css by first making a new class that extends a com.google.gwt.resources.client.CssResource and then I define the a css inside mycss.css

Comment: Ok, show your css and we can see where the problem is.

Comment: updated my question with a code.

Comment: You apply "height:25px" to a cell in a table row. Do you see this style when you inspect this cell in your browser? Is it applied or ignored?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `ensureInjected()` before applying the style:

```
MyResrouces.INSTANCE.MyCSS().ensureInjected()
```